# Transaction isolation level for a table in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, isolation-level, database-table, isolation

It's more a confirmation of what I thought rather than a question. Can one change the isolation level on a table-basis in SQL Server or can it only be defined/changed on a session level as by the statement below?

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

So there is nothing in Microsoft SQL Server like?

```
ALTER DATABASE SET DEFAULT TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

or something like?

```
CREATE TABLE T(A INT) TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

Related questions and answers which I have read:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221548/is-it-possible-to-set-default-transaction-isolation-for-all-connections-in-sql-s
- [how to change isolation level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536805/how-to-change-isolation-level)
- [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=The%20transaction%20isolation%20levels%20define,are%20referenced%20by%20the%20read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=The%20transaction%20isolation%20levels%20define,are%20referenced%20by%20the%20read).

Comment: well, yes and no. Some table hints are the logical equivalent of certain isolation levels -  like the very abused NOLOCK hint. There is a SERIALIZABLE hint. Hints must be applied in every query you want to affect. Your question is **very** unusual and I suggest you think long and hard about taking this approach further.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the isolation level for a connection but not for a `table`. You can however set the locking behavior on some joins however that can improve locking contention when executing certain queries.

Answer (score 0):

For **SQL Server**, **transaction isolation level** can be only set on **a session(connection) level** which means ***in between login and logout***.

For example, after setting `SERIALIZABLE` for **transaction isolation level**:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
GO
```

Then, log out:

```
exit
```

Then, log in again:

```
sqlcmd /S DESKTOP-HN1U0ME\SQLEXPRESS /E
```

Then, **transaction isolation level** is reset to `READ COMMITTED`:

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS
GO

Set Option                  Value
--------------------------- --------------
textsize                    4096
language                    us_english
dateformat                  mdy
datefirst                   7
lock_timeout                -1
quoted_identifier           SET
arithabort                  SET
ansi_null_dflt_on           SET
ansi_warnings               SET
ansi_padding                SET
ansi_nulls                  SET
concat_null_yields_null     SET
isolation level             read committed <- Here
```